# DRF: testing POST method using Client()

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a class that accepts the dictionary list - `data = [{}, {}]` . If I send data via Postman, everything will work but the problem with testing POST class method.

The error is

```
FAIL: test_vendor_from_csv_create (vendors.tests.VendorCsvCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/y700/projects/solution/apps/vendors/tests.py", line 128, in test_vendor_from_csv_create
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

**views.py**

```
class CsvToDatabase(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        r_data = request.data
        for data in r_data:
            if data['nda'] == '':
                data['nda'] = None
                ...
                #some logic
            serializer = VendorsCsvSerializer(data=data)
            try:
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()
            except ValidationError:
                return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**test.py**

```
class VendorCsvCreateTest(APITestCase):

    #API
    def test_vendor_from_csv_create(self):
        url = reverse('csv_vendor_create')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I assume the problem is `format='json'`. If this is the case, how do I transfer the data in the right format? If the reason is different, can you give me a solution, please!
And I don't understand at all why `status = 404` and not `400` if it's a data problem. If I do `print(url)`, it returns a real page url. If set `data = []` empty list - `status=200` return.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('csv_upload/', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='csv_upload'),
    path('from_csv_create/', CsvToDatabase.as_view(), name='csv_vendor_create'),
    path('create/', VendorsCreateView.as_view(), name='vendor_create'),]
```

Comment: Please provide urls.py

Comment: @AndreyNelubin I made update of my question

Comment: May ```some logic``` raise Http404?

Comment: Yes, you are right I have `get_object_or_404 `in my serializer. That's what caused the mistake. Thank you for the right idea!